# githubで開発をしているのですが、branchの変更をmasterにmergeしたのですがうまくいきません

Tags: git

Github上にリポジトリを作成して、ブランチdevelopを作成いたしました。
developブランチをmasterにmergeしたいのですが、どのようなやりかたがベストですか？

現在は、ローカルにリポジトリをクローンしていて、
`git branch`でmasterにいることを確認。
 `git checkout -b　develop`でdevelopブランチに変更。
`git pull`で更新。
変更したものをmasterにmergeさせたいのですが、やりかたがわかりません...
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: git pull で更新とありますが、これは何を pull している想定でしょうか。 github 上の develop ブランチでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

masterブランチにdevelopブランチの変更をmergeするには、以下のコマンドを実行します。

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

また、ローカルでmasterブランチに反映した変更をGithub上のリポジトリに反映するには、以下のコマンドを発行します。

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: この場合は、masterをローカルにクローンした場合でしょうか？
それとも、developをクローンしてそのリポジトリ内でのコマンドでしょうか？
そこは、関係ないでしょうか？

Comment: この場合は、ローカルにmasterブランチとdevelopブランチをcloneした場合を考えています。git pullコマンドを使えば、cloneしていないブランチをマージすることができます。